# Errors when binding selectedItem on a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to databind the selected item of a combobox to a c# property. When i do the following, the property get the value "Suite.Module.RateExperiment.ViewModels.ChamberViewModel"(which is not the value of the selected item in the combobox):

```
    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="ChamberName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ChamberCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedChamber}">
    </ComboBox>
```

And c#:

```
public string SelectedChamber
    {
        get { return _selectedChamber; }
        set
        {
            _selectedChamber = value;
            UpdateChart();
        }
    }
```

Am i binding wrong since this property gets this value?

Comment: `SelectedChamber` property should be of type `ChamberViewModel`, try changing it accordingly.

Comment: what @sthotakura said (SelectedChamber is a string and does not have any "ChamberName" property), also, don't forget to raise propertychanged in the setter of SelectedChamber.

Comment: Yes you are completely right, cant say why i missed that :) many thx. I am new - how do i mark your answer as the answer for this question since it is just a comment?

Comment: Glad, it did help, I will add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedChamber` property should be of type `ChamberViewModel`, try changing it as below:

```
public ChamberViewModel SelectedChamber
    {
        get { return _selectedChamber; }
        set
        {
            _selectedChamber = value;
            UpdateChart();
        }
    }
```